# Capitalize first letter of each numbered line

Tags: ruby

I can't figure out how to skip the numbers (ex. 1., 2., 3.). I am not supposed to modify the string, but still need to capitalize all the first letter of each line (ignoring the numbers). Perhaps I could use `each_line` and `sub`, maybe `match` method.

```
1.     i was just doing this problem.
2. also eating so much food.
3.     it was nice listening to the Mahler.
```

To

```
1.     I was just doing this problem.
2. Also eating so much food.
3.     It was nice listening to the Mahler.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) to update several lines:

```
str = <<TEXT
1.     i was just doing this problem.
2. also eating so much food.
3.     it was nice listening to the Mahler.
TEXT

puts str.gsub(/^(\d+\.[ \t]+)(\w)/) { "#{$1}#{$2.upcase}" }
```

Output:

```
1.     I was just doing this problem.
2. Also eating so much food.
3.     It was nice listening to the Mahler.
```

- `^` matches the beginning of a line
- `(\d+\.[ \t]+)` captures the beginning of a numbered line, i.e. one or more digits, followed by a literal dot and spaces / tabs
- `(\w)` captures a single word character

The first capture group is returned unmodified: `#{$1}`, whereas the second capture group is upcased: `#{$2.upcase}`

Since [`upcase`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-upcase) only affects letters, you could also `upcase` everything up to and including the first letter:

```
puts str.gsub(/^\d+\.[ \t]+\w/, &:upcase)
```

Comment: Your last line is very nice. Why `[ \t]` rather than `\s`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland `\s` would match newlines, e.g. `"4.\na regular paragraph"`

Comment: I had assumed from the example that all lines begin with a digit, but that's a good point. `[ \t]+`, not `[ \t]*`?

Answer (score 1):

### Use Pre-Match and Post-Match Variables

There might be more efficient ways to do this, but a simple way is to use the [pre-match](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/MatchData.html#method-i-pre_match) and [post-match](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/MatchData.html#method-i-post_match) special variables to print the unmodified portions of each line while still invoking [String#upcase](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-upcase) on its first letter. For example:

```
text = <<'EOF'
1.     i was just doing this problem.
2. also eating so much food.
3.     it was nice listening to the Mahler.
EOF

text.each_line { |line| line =~ /\p{Alpha}/; print $`, $&.upcase, $' }
```

This will correctly print:

```
1.     I was just doing this problem.
2. Also eating so much food.
3.     It was nice listening to the Mahler.
```

while still returning the original, unmodified string:

> #=> "1.     i was just doing this problem.\n2. also eating so much food.\n3.     it was nice listening to the Mahler.\n"

Answer (score 1):

Presumable, the modified string is to be kept, so I'd suggest something like:

```
str=
%{1.     i was just doing this problem.
2. also eating so much food.
3.
4.     It was nice listening to the Mahler.}

new_str = str.each_line.map { |l| l.sub(/[a-z]/i) { |c| c.upcase } }.join
puts new_str
  # 1.     I was just doing this problem.
  # 2. Also eating so much food.
  # 3.
  # 4.     It was nice listening to the Mahler.
```

This does not alter `str`:

```
puts str
  # 1.     i was just doing this problem.
  # 2. also eating so much food.
  # 3.
  # 4.     It was nice listening to the Mahler.
```

Alternatively, you could add a capture group and reference its value in the block:

```
str.each_line.map { |l| l.sub(/([a-z])/i) {  $1.upcase } }.join
```